# Unity WebGL cookies don't work

Tags: javascript, php, unity-game-engine

Anyone know why this set/get cookie script doesn't work in Unity WebGL?
The scripts are stored as a javascript plugin in the unity project.

When called from C#, the script doesn't set the cookies.

I call it to set the cookie, then when I go back to the same site and try reading the cookies, they don't exist - just returns blank.

```
setCookie: function (cname, cvalue, exdays) {
   var d = new Date();
   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
   var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
   document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
   console.log('set cookie='+document.cookie);
}


getCookie: function (cname) {
   var ret="";
   var name = cname + "=";
   var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
   console.log('get cookie='+decodedCookie);
   var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
           c = c.substring(1);
       }
       if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
           ret=c.substring(name.length, c.length);
           break;
       }
   }
   var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(ret) + 1);
   writeStringToMemory(ret, buffer);
   return buffer;
},
```

Here is how I call them.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class LocalLogin : MonoBehaviour {

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern string getCookie(string name);

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void setCookie(string cname, string cvalue, int exdays);

void Start() {
   setCookie("session","ruh3uhnoh",7);
   setCookie("userID","id123",7);

   string session=getCookie("session);
   string id=getCookie("userID");
   ....
}
```

Both are always blank. Anyone know what's going on? I tried it in firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Your javascript needs to stringify parameter strings before it can use them. For example, in getCookie: var name = Pointer_stringify(cname) + "=";